# Show that the complex integral is zero for any closed, piece wise smooth path

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\gamma$ is a closed, piecewise smooth path and suppose $n \neq -1$.  Show that $\int_\gamma z^n dz = 0$

I've spent way too much time with this problem.  I need a push in the right direction.  I've basically been trying to show that this function has an antiderivative on some region, but is that enough or even the right path?

Comment: Yes but I think I have to show that Cauchy's theorem is applicable to the particular function.

Comment: Well, you can only do that for $n \geq 0$, since you would then have function(s) holomorphic everywhere in the complex plane. For negative n, you have a pole at the origin. This is an issue if your path encloses the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$z^n$ has an antiderivative $\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}$. Whenever you have that, and a piecewise smooth closed path,
$$
        \int_{\gamma}z^{n}dz = \int_{a}^{b}\gamma(t)^{n}\gamma'(t)dt = \int_{a}^{b}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{(\gamma(t))^{n+1}}{n+1}dt=\left.\frac{(\gamma(t))^{n+1}}{n+1}\right|_{t=a}^{b} =0.
$$
People tend to forget that they can still use Calculus in cases like this. The problem with $n=-1$ is the anti-derivative because you need a branch of the logarithm. There it depends on the path.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\gamma$ is piecewise smooth, we can write $\gamma = \gamma_1 + \cdots + \gamma_r$ where for each $i$, $\gamma_i$ is smooth and $\gamma_m(1) = \gamma_{m+1}(0)$ for $1 \le m \le r-1$. Since $\gamma$ is closed, $\gamma_1(0) = \gamma_r(1)$. Thus

\begin{align}\int_\gamma z^n\, dz &= \sum_{i = 1}^r \int_{\gamma_i} z^n\, dz = \sum_{i = 1}^r \int_0^1 [\gamma_i(t)]^n\gamma_i'(t)\, dt = \sum_{i = 1}^r\frac{[\gamma_i(t)]^{n+1}}{n+1}\bigg|_{t = 0}^1\\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^r\frac{[\gamma_i(1)]^{n+1} - [\gamma_i(0)]^{n+1}}{n+1}\\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^{r-1} \frac{[\gamma_{i+1}(0)]^{n+1} - [\gamma_i(0)]^{n+1}}{n+1} + \frac{[\gamma_r(1)]^{n+1} - [\gamma_r(0)]^{n+1}}{n+1}\\
& = \frac{[\gamma_r(0)]^{n+1} - [\gamma_1(0)]^{n+1}}{n+1} + \frac{[\gamma_1(0)]^{n+1} - [\gamma_r(0)]^{n+1}}{n+1}\\
&=0\end{align}